# What model to use for sales forecasting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, lstm, forecasting

I want to predict company's sales. I tried with LSTM but all the examples that I found only use two variables (time and sales).

https://www.kaggle.com/freespirit08/time-series-for-beginners-with-arima
This page mentioned that time series only use two variables but I think that is not suficient to build a good forecast. After this, I found different 'multiple features' options like polynomial regression with PolynomialFeatures from sklearn or regression trees. I haven't write a script with these last algorithms yet, then I wanna know your recommendations about what model to use.

Thanks.

Comment: I see this is your first question on StackOverflow. Unfortunately it does not adhere to the standards so please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and edit or delete your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is far too broad as written. You need to describe your problem better. In your question, you've asked about two different types of data: Time Series data, and Regression. Without knowing more about the data you have to work with, it's impossible to make any answers that would meaningfully help you. You could try the [datascience.se] stack site, since this question is not about code

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Facebook's Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html), which allows you to take into account *additional regressors*, or [Amazon's DeepAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/aws-forecast-recipe-deeparplus.html).

But I also have seen forecasting models based not on ARIMA style time series but on simple linear regression with extensive feature engineering (features=store+product+historical values) in production.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Prophet. As this has certain advantages over conventional models like ARIMA:

It take cares of empty value well.

Tunning its parameters is way easier and intuition based.

Traditional time series forecasting model expects data points to be in consistent time interval. However, that’s not the case with “Prophet”. Time interval need not to be same throughout.